# Browser extension to indicate whether the link was already opened or not

Tags: web-browser, plug-in

When searching for some info I find myself opening the same pages over and over again sometimes going round within couple of pages because it is not obvious if link will lead to the same page or not.

I wonder if there is any plugin to alter how link appears on the page to indicate that this page is already in the history, and optionally show the counter and date of last open.

Any clue? Or do I need to implement it myself?

Comment: Welcome Jurijs!  Interesting question.  I don't have an answer at this time, but I want to mention that most browsers (definitely Firefox) will change the color of links after you visit them once.  In Firefox, you can change the "Unvisited" and "Visited" colors via Options -> Fonts & Colors -> Colors.